# JSF and spring web flow integration

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

After follow [JSF integration]: http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-faces.html, we use org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter to adapt SWF request to JSF listener as the following.

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
    <property name="defaultHandler">
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />
    </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Maps logical view names to Facelet templates in /WEB-INF (e.g. 'search' 
    to '/WEB-INF/search.xhtml' -->
    <bean id="faceletsViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" /> 
    <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Dispatches requests mapped to org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller 
    implementations -->
    <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />

    <!-- Dispatches requests mapped to flows to FlowHandler implementations -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>
```

However, all EL expression in action attribute are not resolved but treat as string and pass to SWF to perform transaction. Hence, the following code in logon.xhtml will result in invalid transaction of #{logonController.doLogin}.

```
    <h:commandButton type="submit" id="login" value="Login"
    action="#{logonController.doLogin}" />
```

Is there any way for SWF to resolve the EL expression in action attribute of commandButton and involve the backing bean before return the resulted string to SWF to perform the transaction?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try `action="logonController.doLogin"`. Make sure the bean logonController is a spring managed one.

Comment: JSF and Spring MVC are parallel technologies, they do the same, but in a very different way. JSF has its own navigation handler. So that kind of experiment of mixing them won't work or will end up causing you lot of troubles.

Comment: What is logonController.doLogin? Where is it specified before being accessed in commandButton?

Comment: Nikhil Talreja: logonController is a managed bean and spring compoent as describe in [JSF 2 + Spring 3 integration example] (http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/)

Comment: Xtreme Biker: SWF and JSF are preselected technologies in our project. We need to find a best way to integrate them and use the best feature of both. Target to use the flow.xml of SWF to manage the page flow and component based controller of JSF. At this moment, ActionListener attribute should able to involve the JSF managed bean. However, I wonder if there is any better way to use the Action attribute with JSF and SWF.

Comment: Prasad: logonController.doLogin is a method of a spring bean (which used as a managed bean in JSF)